# Flake8: Ignore specific warning for entire file

Tags: python, flake8

The [*Ignoring Errors*](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/3.1.1/user/ignoring-errors.html) docs currently list a way of ignoring a particular error for a particular line:

```
example = lambda: 'example'  # noqa: E731
```

... and a way of ignoring *all* errors for an entire file:

```
# flake8: noqa

from foo import unused
function_that_doesnt_exist()
x = 1+       2
```

... and a couple of ways, either through config or through command-line options, of disabling a particular error *globally* across an entire project.

But what if I want to ignore a *particular* error across the entirety of a *single* file - for instance, to disable warnings about unused imports in an `__init__.py` barrel file that just imports a bunch of classes so that code from other packages can import them from it in turn? The docs don't seem to hint at any syntax for this. Is it possible?

Comment: For your particular example, the officially recommended method (IIRC) is to give an explicit `__all__` declaration that lists the imported stuff.

Comment: @MarkAmery, did any of the answers work for you?

Comment: @DanielWalker they both work; neither does *exactly* what I asked for.

Answer (score 206):

As of Flake8 3.7.0 you can do this using the `--per-file-ignores` option.

Command line example

```
flake8 --per-file-ignores="project/__init__.py:F401 setup.py:E121"
```

Or in your config file

```
per-file-ignores =
    project/__init__.py:F401
    setup.py:E121
    other_project/*:W9
```

See the documentation here: http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/options.html?highlight=per-file-ignores#cmdoption-flake8-per-file-ignores

It is not possible to place a `noqa` comment for specific codes at the top of a file like you can for individual lines. `# flake8: noqa: F401` may at first appear to work, but it's actually being detected as only `# flake8: noqa`, which means "ignore *all* messages in the file".

Comment: To store a `per-file-ignores` entry in a `tox.ini` file put it in the `[flake8]` section.

Answer (score 38):

Before version 3.7.0, ignoring specific errors was only implemented [per-line](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/3.0.4/user/ignoring-errors.html#in-line-ignoring-errors) but not per-file.

The feature was discussed in [issue #324](https://github.com/PyCQA/flake8/issues/324) and the project chose not to implement. An implementation was proposed in [this merge request](https://gitlab.com/pycqa/flake8/merge_requests/192), which nobody has followed up on.

However, some extensions have emerged to address the problem:

- [discontinued] [`flake8-per-file-ignores`](https://github.com/snoack/flake8-per-file-ignores) lets you ignore specific warning/errors for specific files via an entry in the config.
- [`flake8-putty`](https://github.com/jayvdb/flake8-putty) claims to do the same, but hasn't been updated for a while.

Comment: From the `flake8-per-file-ignores` repo: "This flake8 extension has been discontinued in favour of the `per-file-ignores` option built into flake8 3.7.0 and above. But be aware that the built-in option uses different syntax." Here's a versioned [link](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/4.0.1/user/options.html#cmdoption-flake8-per-file-ignores) to the flake8 website's documentation on that option.

Answer (score 8):

I implemented a flake8 plugin [`flake8-in-file-ignores`](https://github.com/bagerard/flake8-in-file-ignores) to allow adding "ignore" rules in the file itself (as opposed to the built-in config approach), the plugin uses the following syntax

```
# flake8-in-file-ignores: noqa: E731,E123
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you!