# Ignore whole folders for particular flake8-docstrings error

Tags: python-3.x, flake8

Is there a way to ignore errors which occurs in specified directory?

For instance, I have `D103 Missing docstring in public function` error
in every file inside `/foo` directory and I would like to omit the error.

Is it possible to set such setting in `setup.cfg` file?

Comment: Do you mind ignoring this error globally?

Comment: [Ooh! Your question's answered here!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48153886/5223757) Just use globs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flake8: Ignore specific warning for entire file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48153886/5223757)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of Flake8 3.7.0 you can do this on a [per-file basis](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/options.html#cmdoption-flake8-per-file-ignores). So for you this would look like:

```
per-file-ignores =
    foo/*:D103
```